# Node-Red: "Error: <nodename> node not deployed" on Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red

Last week I got to know node-red (what a potential!), and after installing it on a Raspberry Pi B+ and following the basic tutorials, I'm experiencing some issues.

When I follow the Inject + Debug node example, wire them, and deploy them, I get the message "Deploy sucessfull". So far so good. I'm running it locally on http:// localhost:1880.

Then when I click the Inject node or the Debug node, it says: "Error: Inject node not deployed" or "Error: Debug node not deployed".

Anyone know how to fix this error? Is it a server problem?

Comment: Facing the same error..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node Red not automatically loading flows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092794/node-red-not-automatically-loading-flows)

Answer (score 4):

Was having the same issues and discovered the flow that I was working on was disabled.
You can tell the flow is disabled when the lettering on its tab is in italic and there is a circle with a diagonal line through it ahead of the lettering.
Double click the flow tab and change "status" to "enabled".

Answer (score 1):

Just tried something and it worked:

When you run **node --max-old-space-size=128 red.js**, the command line shows you "cannot find flows_raspberrypi.json"

So I

- 1) created a flow (as in the examples) 2) Exported it as
  "flows_raspberrypi.json" 3) Stopped node-red  4) Started it again

Bingo! It picked this flow up, which then "sucessfully injected".

Now just create your own flows...

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting same problem of :- Node-red Error: inject node not deployed.

When I have install dashboard on Node-Red which was not working, and started giving error when I hit inject node.

So I manually deleted the files (flows-raspberrypi.json, package.json, settings.js) and also folders (lib, node_modules) from the path /home/pi/.node-red

I used vnc-viewer to delete manually files & folders. Just login to vnc-Viewer and open the file manager and paste the path "/home/pi/.node-red" & delete all the files. Reboot the Raspberry-Pi and start Node-Red, it will function normally, even after installing dashboard it is working.

**NOTE**:**It will delete all your flows and install nodes from Node-Red. So keep backup of your flows.**

Comment: I also had similar issue after I added some UI node. After deploy - flows does now work. I removed UI nodes & every unused nodes and it works now