# Node-Red: "Error: inject node not deployed" on Raspberry Pi

Tags: json, node.js, raspberry-pi, node-red

I have the same problem as described here [Node-Red: "Error: <nodename> node not deployed" on Raspberry Pi B+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997575/node-red-error-nodename-node-not-deployed-on-raspberry-pi-b/25028263#25028263) but on a Pi model B.

The answer provided does not solve the problem for me, but I do not have enough reputation to comment or vote on that posting.

I tried the export and restart procedure per that post, and found my exported file in node-red/lib/flows, but the file name was flows_raspberrypi.json.json. So, I tried again but left ".json" out of the library name. That created the correct file.

However, on restart it still complained that "Flows file not found : flows_raspberrypi.json". The file is in node-red/lib/flows. But when I import it, it is not as I left it (only has one node instead of two wired together). Attempting to repair it only gets me the same "inject node not deployed" error.

Since it is behaving wierdly, I tried re-installing per https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-hosting-node-red without success.  Has anyone gotten it to work?  Hints?

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your flows_raspberrypi.json file in the first node-red installation directory. e.g for me its /home/pi/node-red

it will find the file then, and inject the flow.

Comment: That eliminated the error on startup, but otherwise the system still behaves the same way.  So, it appears that the file is now found, but the node is still not deployed.

Comment: I noticed that the file only had one line in it for a debug node.  I tried to recreate the file with an inject and a debug node, but saving only saved the inject node.  I restarted, and now the inject does not complain about not being deployed, but the debug node got dropped.  So I added it back in, deployed, and tried injecting.  No error!  But no output either.  Clicking the button on the debug node, now it complains that it has not been deployed.  What is the flows_raspberrypi.json file for?  And why does it only contain one line of text when I created it with two nodes on the screen?

Comment: Actually, for some reason the Node Red doesn't save the changes into the flows_raspberrypi.json. I haven't been able to configure out why yet. But if you introduce the another inject and debug node, it ll tell give you the same error of inject node not deployed. however, If you save export that file to library. And copy paste that file as flows_raspberrypi.json. on start up your code will work fine.

Comment: No luck.  No matter how many nodes appear on my screen or are selected, saving to library only writes one line.  And, copying it to <node-red>/flows_raspberrypi.json eliminates the error on startup, but does not change the behavior.  There are no errors even in verbose mode.

Comment: Grasping... I don't know if this is related or just a fact of life on a Pi, but the Node Red UI is very sluggish.  (I'm using VNC to access over wifi.)  Even if I am doing nothing the performance meter shows the Pi "idling" at about 20% utilization.  If I kill the browser, it goes down close to zero.  So, just starting Midori in Node Red seems to tax the processor.  Unusual?  Or expected?

Comment: Try this. Which seems to be working for me. 
If you have any other distribution such as ubuntu. download Node Red on it, and other components. Design your flow there, test it and when you are done copy paste the flow onto the raspberry pi into the flow_raspberrypi.json 

yes, Node Red GUI is sluggish on Raspberry Pi but you can expect that. 

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Asif, but I don't have ubuntu, nor another machine.  Does anyone have a working file (flow_raspberrypi.json) in a public repository?