# Node Red not automatically loading flows

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, node-red

I have succesfully installed nodered on my raspberry-pi.But the problem is each time i write a flow,i have to save the flow into flows_raspberrypi.json and restart nodered server. How to make it automatically save the nodes.

Comment: This might be a file permissions problem? Can the user running node-RED write files in the install directory? Who is the owner of flows_raspberrypi.json?

Comment: It was a permission problem. I changed to a different browser and the flows are getting saved

Answer (score 4):

2 possible things.

1) If you created there flow file by hand then you probably need to create a file called flows_raspberrypi_creds.json containing:

`{}`

2) assuming no errors in either the flow file or the creds file then node-red will load a file based on the machines hostname to start with, you can override this by passing a name on the command line:

`$node red bob`

will load bob.json & bob_creds.json

If neither of those work run `node red -v` to show more detailed error messages.

Comment: It is not getting saved whatever i do in nodered. As soon as i refresh my nodered webpage it is lost. The only way i am able to do is copy the nodes to flows_raspberrypi.json and restart nodered.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really the best place to debug problems like this, you will probably do better on the mailing list or with a github issue. But as a start, stop node-red, delete flow_raspberrypi.json and flowS_raspberrypi_creds.json, restart node red with the -v option. Create your flow, hit the deploy button. If it still doesn't work, post the console output to the mailing list for review.

Comment: I removed the flow file and tried.. But when i am doing a sudo node red.js it is giving as

[red]Flows file not found : flows_raspberrypi.json

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, eventually figured out that node-red was loading my flows from:

```
/home/pi/.node-red/
```

This is supposed to be controlled by the settings.js file in your main node-red directory. Although mine was commented out, which is supposed to then load the flows from the main install directory.

To fix mine I edited my settings.js located in the node-red main install folder by changing this:

```
//userDir: '/home/nol/.node-red/',
```

to this:

```
userDir: '/home/pi/.node-red/',
```

It looks like a fault with node-red to me, will have a quick look when I get chance to see if I can see the code in their Git repository causing the problem. If I can't figure it out I will raise an issue.

Your username could be different to my default pi one, if so just change the line above to reflect your username.

Also delete any files that are in your /home/pi/.node-red/ folder. I had:

```
.config.json
.flows_raspberrypi.json
flows_raspberrypi.json
```

Until these were deleted and node-red restarted I got node not deployed errors and other strange problems.

Hopefully this will fix it for you like it did for me.

Comment: StevenH: what you describe is brand new functionality in the 0.10.4 release - it will not be related to the original question which dates back from last September.